# How to send GCM notification using pure python 2.6

Tags: python, post, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to write a simple script which should check **GCM** registration_ids
in other word a try to recreate **cURL** request

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Authorization:key=auth_key" \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -d '{"registration_ids": ["reg_key"], "data": {"test": "test"}}' \
 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send'
```

in *pure* python

this is my code

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("android.googleapis.com")
conn.connect()
conn.set_debuglevel(1)

body = {}
body['data'] =  {'test': 'test', 'dry-run' : True}
body['registration_ids'] = [key]
print "Send data \n" + str(body)
conn.putrequest('POST', '/gcm/send', str(body))
conn.putheader('Authorization', 'key='+auth_key)
conn.putheader('Content-Type','application/json')
conn.putheader('Content-Length', "%d" % len(str(body)))
conn.endheaders()
response = conn.getresponse()
```

for some reason even though my cURL work fine, when I use python I get response from server like these

```
send: 'POST /gcm/send HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nAuthorization: key=auth_key\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 252\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n'
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
header: Content-Length: 1433
header: Date: Thu, 12 Feb 2015 17:07:54 GMT
header: Server: GFE/2.0
header: Connection: close
```

so please help me to figure out what i'm doing wrong, thanks in advance.

**PS** if i'm omit  Content-Length header in python script, i'll get 411 Content Length required, despite of cURL does not contain this header. Another mystery for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for answers, i end up with this

```
    body = {}
    body['data'] =  {'test': 'test', 'dry-run' : True}
    body['registration_ids'] = [key]
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain', 'Authorization':'key='+auth_key}
    print "Send data \n" + str(body)
    conn.request('POST', '/gcm/send', json.dumps(body), headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
```

I don't know why this works and code in my question don't, may be some one can explain it?

PS doing just `json.dumps(body)` doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `content-type` is json, but the data you are sending is just a string, you might want to use `json.dump()` method to convert your dictionary.

You might want to check out the answers in this post: [Python JSON POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708628/python-json-post-request)

Comment: 'json.dump()' doesn't solve the problem, but your link to another post is very helpful.